# Generic parameter 'D' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, vapor

Here is the code.

```
var migrations = MigrationConfig()
migrations.add(model: Token.self, database: .psql)
services.register(migrations)
```

I don't know much about setting up a database using Swift. The above code is a part of a Swift code that suposedly working but when I ran the code on Xcode (12.0.1) I get the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'DatabaseIdentifier<Token.Database>' to expected argument type 'DatabaseIdentifier<Token.Database>' *

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I recall this being a bug that was introduced when Swift <strike>5.1.3 (I think?)</strike> 5.2 was released.

First off, make sure that your `Token` model's `Database` type is `PostgreSQLDatabase`. Second, try using `DatabaseIdentifier.psql` instead of the shorthand when registering the migration. I think that is what we used to sort it out.

Comment: Correct, details here https://forums.swift.org/t/vapor-3-swift-5-2-regression/34764

Comment: Thank you for the info. You are right. The code runs on Xcode 11.2 and below(Swift 5.1) but not on 11.4 which runs Swift 5.2